# How to set js as background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing my own website and I want a moving matrix background. I found a moving matrix-js which I put in my index. I can't set the js as a 'background' so my text is placed beneath the js.

Btw the design is made with CSS and XHTML. Do I need to do something with the z-index?

Thanks in advance!

http://smcv4001.stellamariscollege.net/stellan2.0

Comment: Always put all relevant code and markup (minimal, of course) **in** the question, don't just link. Links rot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css, define your canvas to be position absolute and z-index -1

```
#q {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]I would use z-index in the CSS. The easiest way is probably adding `z-index: -1` to the CSS of the background, and `position: absolute; top:200px` to the text (of course you can change the distance to the top). The standard value of z-index is > -1, so it will be behind all other things on the page. `position: absolute` is to force overlay of the text over the background. Then it looks like the image in this post.